# c++ console mouse events

Tags: c++, console, mouseevent

Are there any possibilities to get mouse events in a windows console application and even if the console window isn't active and for example Word or any other application is active.

I want a notification if the user selected an desktop item(s) and copied or moved it somewhere else.

Comment: This is going to environment-specific, although I assume you're on Windows. Look into [Mouse Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645601(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Mouse_Messages), although your problem seems more like a generalised filesystem watching mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Windows expert. What I describe works for Linux, but I expect a similar mechanism to exist in Windows.

The "Desktop" metaphore is essentially implemented through a directory. The desktop is a big, full-screen file browser (in Windows it literally is).

This means in Linux, that any change that is made to the desktop directory can be observed through [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify). Again, I presume that a similar mechanism exists in Windows and that you'll be able to find it using the keywords from the manual page of inotify.